# Start reading a text file after a condition has been meet

Tags: r

I am new to programming in R so any help is welcomed and great appreciated.

I have an output file that has a lot of results and I want to start reading from the following line
" Ann. Exc. Prob.  EMA Est.   V[log(EMA)]  At-Site Est.   CI-Low      CI-High"
and stops once there is a line with no text. There are other types of files that can be read so that is why there is a list. The text file can be seen in the image[Text file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtJds.png). Again thanks for all the help.

I have tried using this code

```
LoadFFA <- function(filename, folder.out, TYPE = "PeakFQ_17C",
                    colStandard = TRUE){ # standardize column output names



fileinput<-file.path(folder.out,filename)
fileinput<c(fileinput)

require(data.table)
  if(grepl("PEAKFQSA",TYPE)){ # PeakfqSA Bulleting 17C analysis
    text.list<-lapply(fileinput,readLines)
    skip.rows<-sapply(text.list, grep, pattern = '^Ann. Exc. Prob.\\s+EMA Est.')-1

    PFA<-lapply(seq_along(text.list),function(i) fread(fileinput[i],skip=skip.rows[i]))
  } 
}
```

EDIT

```
require(data.table)
      if(grepl("PEAKFQSA",TYPE)){ # PeakfqSA Bulleting 17C analysis
        text.list<-lapply(fileinput,readLines)
        skip.rows<-sapply(text.list, grep, pattern = '^Ann. Exc. Prob.\\s+EMA Est.')-1
        PFA<-lapply(seq_along(text.list),function(i) read.delim(fileinput[i],skip=skip.rows[i]))
      } 
    }
    print(PFA)
```

Comment: If anybody is curious and ever needs it in the future, I was able to get it to work and it is the code after the EDIT

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that R can start reading a file based on a condition. You can, however, read the entire file and then remove lines that do not fit the condition.

For that you can use `scan()`. This function reads a file line-by-line. Once you have read the entire file, you can easily find the line that match the description. Assuming your file is called text.txt:

```
file = scan("text.txt") #read entire file
start = which(file ==  " Ann. Exc. Prob. EMA Est. V[log(EMA)] At-Site Est. CI-Low CI-High")
end = which(file == "")

file.clean = file[start:end]
```

This code assumes there is only one completely empty line. If there is not the case `end` will contain more than one number and you must add a rule to choose the mimimun value that is greater than `start`.